# why set used in array cannot use echo?

Tags: shell, batch-file

I'm learning batch script in [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_arrays.htm) now, here's a very simple script:

```
@echo off

set a[0]=0
set a[1]=1
set a[2]=2
set a[3]=3
set a[4]=4
set a[5]=5

for /l %%n in (0,1,5) do (echo %a[%%n]%)
```

why result is `"ECHO is off"`

if I write like  `for /l %%n in (0,1,5) do (echo a[%%n])`
I can get

```
a[0]
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
a[5]
```

so why cannot I use echo to get the value of array?

Comment: When the command processor finds a block (anything between parentheses), parses it completely and expand variables to the value they have when the block is evaluated. If you update a variable value within a block, you need to enable delayed expansion for the variable to reflect changes made. Use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and change syntax from `%var%` to `!var!` to make delayed expansion works.

Comment: There's a nice explanation on [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Comment: Interesting site at the given link. Pretty presentation, lot of descriptions and code, but all the examples _are wrong_! There must not be spaces before the equal sign in `set` commands. You may review a detailed description on array management in Batch files at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you shouldn't use percent expansion in a block (here it's a FOR-block), as percents are expanded while the block is parsed.

Use delayed expansion instead.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%n in (0,1,5) do (echo !a[%%n]!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method without having to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
for /l %%n in (0,1,5) do (call echo %%a[%%n]%%)
```

The body of the loop `call echo %%a[%%n]%%` is parsed two times due to `call`; during the first time it becomes `call echo %a[0]%`, supposing the current value of `%%n` is `0`, because `%%` becomes `%`, and during the second time, `%a[0]%` is replaced by the respective value of the variable.

---

In your approach, `echo %a[%%n]%`, the command line interpreter sees two variables to expand, namely `%a[%` and `%n]%`, which are both undefined and become therefore replaced by nothing.